# #include preprocessor macro name space

Tags: c, linux, gcc

This question is to understand the *standard* behavior for header file inclusion (not the one implemented on my compiler).

I have two header files with same names (but contents are different):

```
1) /user/include/myheader.h  # In standard system folder
2) /private/myheader.h       # In my private folder
```

Assume both the headers contains same multiple inclusion prevension macros

```
#ifndef MYHEADER
#define MYHEADER
...
#endif
```

I have C file  `/private/test.c`, which includes both the above headers:

```
#include <myheader.h>  // Includes from standard system folder
#include "myheader.h"  // Includes from the folder where test.c is present
```

Do the  content from both files go into the C file while pre-processing, since each MYHEADER definition has separate name space ? Or the second inclusion will be prevented since MYHEADER is already defined in same namespace ?

Comment: Unless you `#undef MYHEADER` somewhere, the second include will basically include an empty file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[N1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> #### 6.10.3 Macro replacement
>
> ...
> 7 The identiﬁer immediately following the `define` is called the *macro name*. **There is one
> name space for macro names.** Any white-space characters preceding or following the
> replacement list of preprocessing tokens are not considered part of the replacement list for either form of macro.

Emphasis mine.

As written, only the contents of the first `myheader.h` file will be processed.

Answer (score 3):

There is only one namespace for all macros, and all macros go in the same namespace.  Putting stuff in different header files has no effect on this -- they all still go in the same namespace.  So with your example, the first header will define `MYHEADER`, which will cause the second header to be (effectively) ignored.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as "name space" for preprocessor definitions in the C standard<sup>1</sup>. No matter how the `MYHEADER` is defined<sup>2</sup>, the content of the second file will be ignored.

---

<sup>1</sup> The C99 standard, section 6.2.3, defines four name spaces - (1) for labels, (2) for struct/union/enum tags, (3) for members of each structure or union, and (4) for everything else. Preprocessor definitions do not belong in any of these name spaces, because "Macro names and macro parameters are not considered further here, because prior to the semantic phase of program translation any occurrences of macro names in the source file are replaced by the preprocessing token sequences that constitute their macro definitions.".

<sup>2</sup> As far as defining `MYHEADER` goes, you have several options: you can define it in your C file, in a header file, or pass it from the command line using the corresponding option of your C compiler.

Comment: However, the *prase* "name space" appears 19 times in the C11 standard.

Comment: @JohnBode That does not change the correctness of my answer in any way: the word "namespace" is not there in the C11 standard either. I did edit my answer to include more detail from the standard, mostly to show that the "name space" is not applicable to preprocessor definitions.

Comment: the way I read 6.3.10/7 and 6.2.3/1, it sounds like preprocessor definitions occupy a separate name space from ordinary identifiers.

Answer (score 0):

Just one definition will be used because the #define directives have global scope, so the second include will do nothing.

You should use MY_PROJECT_MY_HEADER or something like that in order to prevent those kinds of problems.